# Eclipse DDMS not showing Emulator on restart

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

I'm running Eclipse: Helios. Here's the issue. When I leave my Android Emulator running for about 20 minutes while I'm programming, if I try to install and run my application, I receive this error in the console:

> [2011-07-12 12:27:55 - DatePrinter] Failed to install DatePrinter.apk
> on device 'emulator-5554': Connection refused: connect
>
> [2011-07-12 12:27:55 - DatePrinter] java.net.ConnectException:
> Connection refused: connect
>
> [2011-07-12 12:27:55 - DatePrinter] Launch canceled!

If I close the emulator and run the project again, a new emulator launches and the console shows the emulator starting but the app does not install and the emulator does not show up in DDMS.

If I go to the terminal and type in `adb devices`, I get this error message

> ADB Server didn't ACK
>
> *failed to start daemon*
>
> error cannot connect to daemon

The only way I can fix it that I've found is to close eclipse, kill the adb.exe process and restart eclipse.

Any ideas what could be causing this error/how to debug it?

**Edit**: Starting the emulator through SDK manager does not yield any positive results either.

**Edit 2**: Running adb kill-server and adb start-server yields the same message "ADB Server didn't ACK" although it prints a `"daemon not started, starting it now on port 5037"` right before that.

Comment: Have you tried `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`?

Comment: Yes. adb kill-server does nothing and adb start-server prints out the same "adb server didn't ack" statement.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior on IntelliJ on Mac OSX, so I strongly suspect it is a problem with the adb executable.

Comment: @Otra, could you please check how many adb process running on process manager

Comment: 1, I'm not sure it can start more than one since it binds to a specific port, no?

Answer (score 5):

Though I did not have the same problem as you did. In case of connectivity problems with emulator and Eclipse I use the following:

In the DEVICES window of Eclipse (DDMS perspective) drop down menu (in the upper right corner of the window) select "Reset ADB".

This solves most of connectivity problems, which otherwise will require restart.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

Check whether adb path has been added to environment variable, otherwise try to re-install the SDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the folder `C:/../android-sdk/platform-tools`, the following commands didn't work.

```
adb kill-server
```

Did nothing, and

```
adb start-server
```

resulted in an error.

So I killed the adb process with the task manager and used `adb start-server` again. And it works.

Comment: If you look at my question, I'm fully aware of that solution. I'm asking how to prevent it and what the cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Select `adb` and end the process
3. Go to Eclipse and reset adb
4. Run your app

Answer (score -2):

Check your Anti virus program control dialogs e.g Norton Antivirus and ZoneAlarm 2010.

Make sure that

```
eclipse.exe
emulator.exe
emulator-arm.exe
```

have input and outbound and network connections!

Comment: It can't be a basic connection problem as he is able to connect after restart.